# Abstractionlayer for Database-Access

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to write custom SQL code for mysql and mssql (perhaps more later).

```
var dbSystem = "mssql";
if ("mssql" == dbSystem) {
    var mssqlConn = new SqlConnection(mssqlConnString);
    new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 in NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), c2 int)", mssqlConn).ExecuteNonQuery();
} else {
    var mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConnString);
    new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 in NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, c2 int)", mssqlConn).ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The Problem starts here. I would like to declare the connection via an interface or abstract-class before the if-statement. But it seems not possible, because the command-classes demand explicitly the specific SqlConnection or MySqlConnection.

The problem get's worse if you would like to execute a simple command like `SELECT c1 form t1 where c2 = @value`. Because you have to do the same as above.

Is there an API which serves a workflow like this:

```
IDbConnection conn; // initialized by SqlConnection or MySqlConnection, etc.
IDbCommand cmd = new DbCommand("SELECT c1 form t1 where c2 = @value", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", Type.Int);
```

Problem:

- System.Data.Common.DbCommand is an abstract class
- SqlDbCommand (MySqlDbCommand, etc. ) demand there specific connection
- DbCommand.Properties does not support "Add" with two Parameters ("@placeholer", value) like the Properties of SqlDbCommand
- i don't need/want a full blown ORM; just an interface/abstraction-layer over the existing heterogeneous API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to go would be using [DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h508h681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve a [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Using [DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would give you a [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Setting the [ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of this DbConnection object and calling [Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will result in a opened connection to the desired database.

Using [DbConnection.CreateCommand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you a [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object to use as you wish.

For using a parameterized query you can use [DbCommand.CreateParameter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.createparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will return a [DbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

**Sample**:

```
// MySQL
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient"); 

// MS-SQL
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");  

private void Query(String query,Dictionary<String,object> namesAndValues, System.Data.CommandType commandType)
{
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionString"];

    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            AddParameters(command, namesAndValues);
            using (DbDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                 //
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
private void AddParameters(DbCommand command, Dictionary<String, object> namesAndValues)
{
    String factoryName = factory.GetType().Name;
    DbParameter para;
    foreach (String key in namesAndValues.Keys)
    {
        para = command.CreateParameter();
        switch (factoryName)
        {
            case "SqlClientFactory":
                para.ParameterName = "@" + key;
                break;
             case "OracleClientFactory":
                para.ParameterName = ":" + key;
                break;
            case "OleDbFactory":
                para.ParameterName = "?";
                break;
            case "MySqlClientFactory":
                para.ParameterName = "?" + key;
                break;
        }
        para.Value = namesAndValues[key];
        command.Parameters.Add(para);

    }
}
```

Comment: added using for all statements. Don't forget to clean up commands and readers as soon as you can.

Comment: I also added how you can get the connection string and provider from the config (the `<connectionStrings>` element)

Comment: I've written a blog post about everything here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a `DbProviderFactory` which abstracts the concrete driver implementation away. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For database specific SQL commands you'd need to create some sort of abstraction as well.
Like

```
interface IQueryBuilder{
  string BuildCreateTableQuery();
}
class MySqlQueryBuilder : IQueryBuilder {
}
class SqlQueryBuilder : IQueryBuilder {
}
class OracleQueryBulder : IQueryBuilder{
}
```